# How to add a variable in Automator in "To:" field from Mail?

Tags: automator

I need to pass a variable in Automator in "To:" field from Mail, but I see that it is only supported in the Subject line or Message.

Comment: You can't, use a Run AppleScript action and AppleScript the email to be sent.